Accessing React Navigation 'UseFocusEffect' from within class components
I'm updating a project from React Navigation v4 to v6 and I'm trying to figure out the best way to determine focus on a screen load. With v4, I had something like this:
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

   _someFunction() {
        // stuff happens here when the screen loads
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <NavigationEvents onDidFocus={payload => this._someFunction()} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

// for Redux
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);

Currently, I don't see a way of using v6's UseFocusEvent from within the class. I can create a component and call that from within the class, but then I have to pass everything to the component (which can be a bit much if there's a lot to do on focus). I'm hoping there is a better way?
What I have now (but would like to streamline):
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

//////////////////
// Here's the focus component
//////////////////
function HandleFocus({ props, _someFunction }) {
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            props.setCurTab('Home');
            _someFunction;
        }, [ props, _someFunction ])
    );
    return null;
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

   _someFunction() {
        // stuff happens here when the screen loads
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <HandleFocus
                    props={this.props}
                    _someFunction={()=>this._someFunction()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

// for Redux
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);

Previously: react-native 0.68, react-navigation 4.4.4
Currently: react-native 0.74.3, @react-navigation/native 6.1.18
EDIT:
I haven't seen any responses to this so I'm sharing what I've done. I went instead with adding a listener into my component so that I can use props:
    _handleFocusEvent() {
        // Do some things here.
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._handleFocusEvent()
        this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            this._handleFocusEvent()
        });
    }

